# Implementing IEnumerable<interface> Generic

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I'm brand new to c# and have read threads on the topic, but am still having trouble.  Thanks in advance to your suggestions and advice.

From the top level, I'm implementing an interface that includes a method

```
IEnumerable<Iinterfacetype> methodname(inputtype input)
```

In this case, it seems that I should return an object of type `IEnumerable<Iinterfacetype>`.  In order to do so, I am trying to create a new script that implements `IEnumerable<Iinterfacetype>`.  My script so far, look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace Project3.SimulatedTools.DBImplementations
{
    class Enumerable : IEnumerable<interfacetype>
    {
        List<interfacetype> mylist = new List<interfacetype>();

        public IEnumerator<interfacetype> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return mylist.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Where I have another script called interfacetype.cs which implements Iinterfacetype.

At the original top level, I've set it up like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Iinterfacetype> methodname(inputtype input) 
{
    Enumberable<interfacetype> tempnamehere = new Enumerable();
    return(tempnamehere);
}
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`Project3.SimulatedTools.DBImplementations.Enumerable`' to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Iinterfacetype>`'.  An explicit conversion exists (are  you missing a cast?)

How do I interpret this error?  Did I set up the implementation of `IEnumerable<interfacetype>` correctly?  Why can't I return type `IEnumerable<interfacetype>` when interfacetype implements Iinterfacetype?

---

EDIT:
My top level now looks like this, and I've adjusted my class Enumerable to implement IEnumerable instead of , changing all references to  to .  I no longer get any compile errors, but I'm still not understanding what the original issue is, and haven't set it up to run yet.

```
public IEnumerable<Iinterfacetype> methodname(inputtype input) 
{
    Enumberable tempnamehere = new Enumerable();
    return(tempnamehere);
}
```

Furthermore, is it necessary for me to have an interfacetype : Iinterfacetype, as I've set it up now?  It seems like I never actually use interfacetype, in which case, it would be irrelevant.  If so, why is this the case (that I don't have to implement it)?

Comment: You should use `yield return` and `yield break`, or just return some collection from `System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: Is `linterfacetype` and `intetfacetype` the same type?

Comment: interfacetype implements Iinterfacetype

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at the definiton of `IEnumerable<T>`:

> Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of a specified type

Basically, any type implementing `IEnumerable` enables us to iterate over a given collection.

There are types in the .NET Framework which implement the interface:

`List<T>`,  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, etc.

Instead of implementing the `IEnumerable<T>` yourself, you can use the types supplied by the BCL (Base Class Library) and simply use an object which implements it.
In your case, a `List<interfacetype>` would suffice:

```
public IEnumerable<Iinterfacetype> methodname(inputtype input) 
{
    return new List<interfacetype>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really never create a "new Enumerable", instead you create things that impliment IEnumerable.  The most obvious example would be:

```
var l = new List<string>();
```

This implements `IEnumerable<string>;`